# sql difference between columns from 2 identical tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two different tables (extracted from multiple sources to get these views ) with exact same column names, I am trying to find values from Table A, that are difference from Table B.

Sample data for Table A:

```
     id      |   code   |    dos     |     entry_id   | survey_date
------------+----------+------------+----------------+-------------
   1        | 0120     | 2017-07-02 |      141949406 | 2017-07-04
   2        | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141949394 | 2017-07-04
   3        | 4910     | 2017-07-02 |      141949304 | 2017-07-04
   4        | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141945276 | 2017-07-31
   5        |          |            |                | 2017-07-31
   6        | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141937311 | 2017-07-04
   7        |          |            |                | 2017-07-27
   8        | 0120     | 2017-09-01 |      142080557 | 2017-08-01
   9        |          |            |                | 2017-07-31
   10       |          |            |                | 2017-07-31 
   15       | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141933588 | 2017-07-31
```

Sample Data for Table B:

```
Table B:
    id      |   code   |    dos     |      entry_id  | survey_date
------------+----------+------------+----------------+-------------
   11       | 0150     | 2017-09-05 |      142081004 |
   12       | 0150     | 2017-09-05 |      142082062 |
   1        |          |            |                | 2017-07-04
   16       | 0120     | 2017-07-02 |      141949391 |
   2        |          |            |                | 2017-07-04
   3        | 4910     | 2017-07-02 |      141949304 | 2017-07-04
   3        | 4910     | 2017-07-02 |      141949304 | 2017-07-04
   13       | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141947246 |
   4        | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141945276 | 2017-07-31
   14       | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141943912 |
   5        |          |            |                | 2017-07-31
   6        |          |            |                | 2017-07-04
   15       | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141933588 |
   7        |          |            |                | 2017-07-27
   8        |          |            |                | 2017-08-01
   9        |          |            |                | 2017-07-31
   10       |          |            |                | 2017-07-31
```

I have used

```
select * from table_A except select * from table_b;
```

Result Sample:

```
     id  |  code    |    dos     |       entry_id | survey_date
------------+----------+------------+----------------+-------------
   1        | 0120     | 2017-07-02 |      141949406 | 2017-07-04
   2        | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141949394 | 2017-07-04
   8        | 0120     | 2017-09-01 |      142080557 | 2017-08-01
   6        | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141937311 | 2017-07-04
   15       | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141933588 | 2017-07-31
```

It gives me rows that are different, But I need column values that are different 
Expected Results:

```
     id  |  code    |    dos     |       entry_id | survey_date
------------+----------+------------+----------------+-------------
   1        | 0120     | 2017-07-02 |      141949406 | 
   2        | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141949394 | 
   8        | 0120     | 2017-09-01 |      142080557 | 
   6        | 0150     | 2017-07-02 |      141937311 | 
   15       |          |            |                | 2017-07-31
```

Expected result set id =1 has survey_date value, since that value is part of Table B, I need it to be null. Similarly for Row id=15 every column matched except survey_date and hence result should have all column values to be null except survey_date, How can I achieve this? Sorry if it has been posted earlier

Comment: Changed the description to have expected output

Comment: Does it have to be "select *" or could it be "select id, code,dos,entry_id,survey_date, etc...

Comment: it can be select id, code, dos etc

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is compare each field individually and code in a "case" for what to do when they match or not match from table a and b. Then, you need to overall eliminate rows where the whole row match. Below I'll do that and use row_to_json to assist in comparing the whole rows to each other. There may be a more efficient way than row_to_json, but this should work.

```
select 
 a.id,
 case when a.code=b.code then null 
    else b.code end code,
 case when a.dos=b.dos then null 
    else b.dos end dos,
 case when a.entry_id=b.entry_id then null 
    else b.entry_id end entry_id,
 case when a.survey_date=b.survey_date then null 
    else b.survey_date end survey_date
from table_a a
join table_b b on b.id=a.id
where row_to_json(a) != row_to_json(b)
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, it worked great for the given sample data, I apologize that I did not mention that Table_a  id column isn't primary key neither my sample data is obvious enough to make it clear, it can also have duplicate ids on multiple rows. Join  on one column isn't going to be sufficient enough in that case

Comment: Does this help you find an answer? What IS the primary key then -- you've GOT to have a way to link the two records in each table -- give me that and I'll give you an answer.

Comment: These data feeds that I provided in the sample,  "table_a" data is derived by joining few other tables and "table_b" data has been derived from json columns, which is why I don't have a primary key on either tables.

Comment: I see. So if I found row 1 from table A and row 2 from table B, what lets you know that they're comparable?

Comment: I figured a way to accomplish this, Since those fields are derivable, I extracted id and one column at a time to compare and used except condition to isolate the differences and repeat the same step for the other columns and finally used union on the result set